# How do I configure $this->cwd for symfony2 framework

Tags: php, symfony

I am new to Symfony and I was assigned a Symfony 2 project.Now I am facing some problem with app/console server:run.

The project is a working system, therefore the problem should be because of my limited knowledge in  Symfony framework.

this is what I keep getting

```
proc_open() : CreateProcess failed, error code - 267 in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Process\Process.php on line 246.
```

line 246 is this part

```
  $this->process = proc_open($commandline, $descriptors, $this->processPipes->pipes, $this->cwd, $this->env, $this->options);
```

I have tried changing the $this->cwd to "C:/xampp/htdocs/xxx", it can run but it will have another problem which is after I visit localhost:8000, it shows this

```
Warning: require(app_dev.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\xxx\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Resources\config\router_dev.php on line 30


Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'app_dev.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Resources\config\router_dev.php on line 30
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

EDIT:

I have updated all my files as suggested my Matteo, a few issues came up with the vendors and I have solved it for new (hopefully). However now I am stuck at another problem which is this

```
The given document root directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/xxx/app/../web" does not exist.
```

As mentioned in the comments, I do not have a folder called "web". It was renamed to public. I have already changed the composer.json but it does not seem to do anything.

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "richsage/rms-push-notifications-bundle": "dev-master",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~1.3",
    "ircmaxell/password-compat": "~1.0.3"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "public",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.4-dev"
    }
}
}
```

If I type app/console --version in cmd, it shows Symfony version 2.6.1 - app/dev/debug

Please help me out.

Comment: which version of sf2 and php are you using? take a look at [this old closed bug](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/6496)

Comment: @Matteo Hi, I saw that post a while ago before posting and it leads to another problem.
I am using PHP Version 5.5.15 and symfony version 2.4.2

The weird part about this project is there is no web folder in its project directory.

Comment: try update to the last version (if you can) or verify that the sf 2.6 run fine in your env.

Comment: @Matteo Hi Matteo, I have just created a 2.6.1 Symfony app on my computer and it works. However I am a little afraid of upgrading the project I have now, because I have never used Symfony before, it will be a BIG problem if bugs start appearing from completed parts after the update. Is there any advice you could provide?

Comment: I suggest you to use the last stable version 2.6.1 without problem. There are no BC, only upgrade and update, however check the [UPGRADE files here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony). Hope this help. (My first production project with sf2 was based on the beta of the sf 2.1 )

Comment: Take a look at the [sf2 release roadmap] (http://symfony.com/roadmap): the support for the release 2.4.x is ended so upgrading now is a good task

Comment: I summarized our discussion in an answer for future reference. If you find my help usefull you can accept the answer and upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug as described [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/6496). It is resolved in the current framework version (2.6.1).

So the solution is to upgrade to the current version. You can verify in the UPGRADE files on the [github repo](https://github.com/symfony/symfony) is something is changed but there anren't BC (Break Compatibility).

In addition, your current framework version (2.4.2) is out of support so is a good moment to do this task.

In general is a good practice to upgrade to the last stable version of the framework. Take a look at the [sf2 release roadmap](http://symfony.com/roadmap) for the release process and for the end of support of the various framework release.

Hope this help